# When a website hyperlink is clicked, what is the source IP address of the http request

Tags: amazon-web-services, hyperlink, api-gateway

I am looking to setup a website (that users have logged into) which has a web page with a hyperlink  corresponding to an AWS API Gateway URL. I want to restrict access to the API gateway to requests from the website only.

I thought to do this by restricting the API gateway to the IP address of the website, but I'm not sure which IP address gets used when the hyperlink is clicked. My question is, when the hyperlink is clicked, is the source IP address (according to the HTTPS request) the user's machine IP or is it the website IP address?

Any help's appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IP address would be the IP address of the user making the request; this can be useful and you can certainly limit requests based on the users IP address, however, that may not be the most straightforward way to accomplish the functionality you’ve described.

API Gateway supports the functionality you described through the Cross Origin Resource Sharing, or CORS, setting.

You can read the docs about API Gateways CORS settings [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html).

Basically, you’re going to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your websites url. You can do this in the console or via the AWS CLI with the following command:

```
aws apigatewayv2 update-api --api-id your-api-gateway-id --cors-configuration AllowOrigins="https://www.yourwebsite.com"
```

Comment: Thanks mate that's fantastic. Appreciate the pointer in the right direction as well as the answer!

Comment: @Brad glad its helpful! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If the user is clicking a link (that will navigate the browser to the AWS API), the IP address will be based on the user's machine - or more accurately their public IP address from their ISP.

If your website has been written to call the AWS API directly (server-side), then the IP address would be based on the hosting provider's outbound IP addresses.